# Restrict certain products to specific customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9. Is there a way to make certain products only available to specific customer groups?

If this is not possible with the basic system, is there a free extension that handles that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an open source extension in github: https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

It's unsupported but it has worked in production for years.